# Why can't a fork bomb be killed in zsh in the same way as it's killed in bash?

Tags: debian, terminal, cgroups, fork

I wanted to make my system a little bit more resilient to fork bombs. This can be partially achieved by using systemd's `DefaultTasksMax` parameter, or by using `cgroup`'s `pids` controler for all valid shells, for instance via cgrulesengd:

```
*:bash               pids                             users/shells/bash/
*:zsh                pids                             users/shells/zsh/
```

And a small script to set limits for shells:

```
CGDIR=/sys/fs/cgroup/
mkdir -p       $CGDIR/pids/users/shells/
echo '8192'  > $CGDIR/pids/users/shells/pids.max
mkdir -p       $CGDIR/pids/users/shells/bash/
echo '2048'  > $CGDIR/pids/users/shells/bash/pids.max
mkdir -p       $CGDIR/pids/users/shells/zsh/
echo '1024'  > $CGDIR/pids/users/shells/zsh/pids.max
```

When I start a terminal with the bash shell and execute `:(){ :|:& };:` in it, nothing really happens. I get 2048 in `pids.current` almost instantly, CPU is utilized in 50-60%. When I close the terminal, the fork bomb dies and everything backs to normal.

When I want to do the same with the terminal with the zsh shell, I get 100% CPU instantly, and after closing the terminal, the fork bomb still kills my system. The only way to fix this is to issue a few times `killall -9 zsh` in a terminal with other shell in it.

Why can't a fork bomb be killed in zsh in the same way as it's killed in bash? I mean, just by closing the terminal the bomb was initiated in.

Comment: What is `$CGDIR`?

Comment: It's just /sys/fs/cgroup/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `bash`, when `fork()` fails with EAGAIN as when the limit it reached (using setrlimit, or using those cgroup pid limits), `bash` sleeps and tries again after 1 second, and then after 2 seconds if it fails again, and then after 4, and then it sleeps for 8 seconds and gives gives up without even trying another fork(!)).

Then with `bash`, as soon as the limit is reached (within a fraction of a second on a quiet system), most of those bash processes are sleeping. That's why fork bombs are a lot less harmful in `bash` than in other shells.

Closing the terminal doesn't kill those processes. Maybe what you're seeing is the fork bomb dying away after a little over 15 seconds (1+2+4+8) when all the processes that have managed to start and have gone to sleep die at the same time 8 seconds after their 4th attempt to fork.

In `zsh`, there is not such retrying and sleeping, all processes fork and exit. When one dies, that frees up a process which can be used by one of the forking ones.

If you want to kill a fork bomb, the easiest it to kill the process group as a whole, using `killall` doesn't work as `killall` needs to gather the list of processes and then send kills individually for each process. That's fine with `bash` where all the processes are sleeping, but not with other shells which spawn processes all the time, so processes can be started between each kill.

You can get the pgid with `ps -j`, and kill the process group with `kill -- "-$pgid"`.

Comment: That makes sense.